# Is the effective tax rate for a digital nomad living in portugal 10%?

Tags: tax-law, income-tax, portugal

I [read online](https://imperiallegal.com/media/news/what-are-tax-benefits-available-in-portugal-for-digital-nomads/) that [someone who earns over ~2800](https://newsblare.com/leadership/careers/remote-workers-portugals-new-digital-nomad-visa-starting-oct-30/) euros per month can live on a [digital nomad visa in Portugal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_nomad#Portugal) and:

> There are several advantages: no taxes on foreign income; 20% tax on income earned in Portugal compared to standard Portuguese income tax rates of up to 48%; social contributions 10% which is considerably less than the standard rate.

Can a person working for a UK or USA company essentially live in Portugal on a digital nomad visa at a 10% tax rate?

Comment: This hypothetical person is a citizen or official resident of some county that is not Portugal, I assume?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite exactly